# How to create user that can use CALL only?

Tags: sql

What must I do in order to make this

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS CLIENT PASSWORD = 'abc';
```

into a User that can not do anything (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `DROP` etc etc) except use `CALL` that would do all the CRUD statements for the User?

Comment: what db platform?

Comment: I am currently using H2.